# C# InstallUtil/ManagedInstallerClass: Why are key value pairs not pass into the installers context parameters collection?

Tags: c#, windows-services, installutil, managedinstallerclass

I pass the service name into the argument list, but when I look in the installers context it is not there:

```
args = new[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "/ServiceName=WinService1" };
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(args);
```

Why are key value pairs not pass into the installers context?

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
{
    foreach (var param in Context.Parameters)
    {
       // ServiceName is not available in the Parameters collection
    } 
}
```

Comment: Probably because they are passed through *stateSaver*.

Answer (score 5):

This is quite old thread, but maybe someone still could use the answer like I could have if it was here earlier :).
Only parameters before location are being passed into the context for the installer.
Try this:

```
args = new[] { "/ServiceName=WinService1", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location };
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(args);
```

Comment: This gives me `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\path\to\exe\ --params' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.` (note, doesn't actually pass the exe's name, only the folder it's in)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
IDictionary dictionary = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>();
dictionary.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, 
               new string [] {"/ServiceName=WinService1"});
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(dictionary);
```

Comment: ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper needs an array of strings.

Comment: @Rookian from your code it takes IDictionary, but see my update if that will help. Sorry if it is totally wrong direction

Comment: @oleksii, cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IDictionary' to 'string[]'