# Self-installing a service that executes with parameters

Tags: c#, service, installation

I have a console application that will optionally self-install itself as a service. This works fine, but I'd like to embed some arguments into the service startup - similar to (for example) Google's Update Service (which has the parameter `/medsvc`)

[image]

So let's say I'd like my service to start

`MyService.exe RUN Test1`

.. so that'd start up `MyService.exe` with the parameters `RUN` and `Test1`.

I can install the service fine, using

```
  ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location});
```

However, there's no parameters on the service. So if I try:

```
  ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location +" RUN Test1"});
```

I get a `FileNotFoundException`. Giving that it's a array, I thought I'd try:

```
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(new[] {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,"RUN","Test1"});
```

.. which gives the same exception, except that it's trying to find the file `RUN` now.

I can't find any specific documentation on how to achieve this - does anyone know if it is possible to embed parameters in with the service executable path? As another example, here's Google's Update Service with parameters - I'd like to ultimately achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to find this out, I hope it's still useful to someone.
First I found out, that you are not supposed to run ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper according to MSDN docs:

> This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be
>   used directly from your code.

Then I found out I could just use my own ProjectInstaller (a component class I added containing a Service Installer and a Service Process Installer) to install the service like this:

```
ProjectInstaller projectInstaller = new ProjectInstaller();
            string[] cmdline = { string.Format("/assemblypath={0} \"/myParam\"", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) };
            projectInstaller.Context = new InstallContext(null, cmdline);

            System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary state = new System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary();
            projectInstaller.Install(state);
```

Be sure to encapsulate your parameters in quotes and escape the quotes, otherwise your parameters will become part of the executable path and fail to start.

The end result will be a new service with the specified properties in your Service Installer and Service Process Installer, and a path just like in your screenshot (with the /medsvc parameter for example).

Answer (score 0):

I use a console application inside my windows service.  The Main method in Program.cs processes the command line args.  The OnStart method starts the console application.  It works great.

[Windows Service to Run Constantly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864673/windows-service-to-run-constantly)

[HybridService Easily Switch Between Console Application and Service](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19351/HybridService-Easily-Switch-Between-Console-Applic)

Answer (score -1):

Only parameters before location are being passed into the context for the installer.
Try this:

```
args = new[] { "/ServiceName=WinService1", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location };
ManagedInstallerClass.InstallHelper(args);
```

Reference from another answer: [Passing Parameter Collection to Service via InstallHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152017/c-sharp-installutil-managedinstallerclass-why-are-key-value-pairs-not-pass-into?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't appear to do anything - although the service installs with that code, it still doesn't have any parameters on the executable path.